# Include directive greyed out

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and need some help. The #include directive is greyed out. What does this mean?

**code**

[image]

Comment: It means the syntax highlighting is working.

Answer (score 2):

This is just syntax highlighting.

Comment: Yes, but why is it grey and not blue like the other C++ commands?

Comment: It's just a convention that many editors use.

Comment: @UAR777 because the person who chose the colours, decided to use different colours for different tokens. Notice also the use of dark red and turquoise.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @UAR777 Try `#if 0 #include <iostream> #endif` to see an actually disabled preprocessor directive.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. Its just the setting on how your IDE highlights pre-processor commands. As you asked in a comment on another answer, `#include` is not an C++ command, its a pre-processor command. The pre-processor of your compiler will deal with that.